# how to use the SELECT?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

please help to solve the problem

a model with a foreign key:

```
class Gender(models.Model):     
    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, 
        blank=True,
    )   


class UserProfile(User):            
    gender = models.ForeignKey(
        Gender,
        verbose_name='Пол',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    phone = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, 
        blank=False,
    )

    objects = UserManager()
```

during initialization of the application she filled out initial_data.json:

```
[
    {
        "model": "app_accounts.Gender",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {
            "gender": "Ж"
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "app_accounts.Gender",
        "pk": 2,
        "fields": {
            "gender": "М"
        }
    }
]
```

form that is displayed on this page:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    gender = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Gender.objects.all(),
    )       
    phone = forms.CharField(
        label='Номер телефона',
        widget=forms.TextInput(),   
        required=False,     
    )

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (  
            'gender',    
            'phone',    
        )
```

the result shows the form in which such values ​​selects:

```
---------
Gendr object
Gendr object
```

please help to bring in the type field values ​​Select:

```
-----
M
Ж
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [`__unicode()__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/instances/#unicode) method to your `Gender` model:

```
class Gender(models.Model):     
    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, 
        blank=True,
    )   

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.gender
```

That way Django will know how to display those `Gender` objects.

Comment: `__str__` instead of `__unicode__` if you're on python 3.x